# jquery-ui button looks disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am guessing I am doing something stupid here and you can point me right direction. I am trying to use jquery-ui "pencil" icon for edit and the icon looks like it is not active. See the html and js below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
        <TITLE>Sample</TITLE>
        <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sample.js"></script>
    </HEAD>
        
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {      
            $( window ).on( "load", function() {
                sample.launch();
            });        
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="applybtn" style="width:65px" value="Click Me" />
    </body>
</HTML>
```

and here is the js file :

```
var sample = sample || {};
(function ($) {
    "use strict";   
    function onApplyBtnClick() {
        var html = '<input type="text" id="schpn12" value=' + "ABCD" + '>';
        html += '<button class="editbtn" >Edit</button>';
        $('<div></div>')
            .html('<span></span>' + html)
            .css("background-color","#FFFFFF")
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
                buttons: {
                    "Apply": function () {                        
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            
            $('.editbtn').button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-pencil"
                },
                text: false
            });
    }
    function launch() {     
        $("#applybtn").click(onApplyBtnClick);
    }
    sample.launch = launch;
}(jQuery));
```

[image: pencil icon looks like not active]

Comment: Since the code for the `.button()` is inside of `onApplyBtnClick()`, this must be executed to properly initialize the button. I would suggest moving the code outside of the functions or into `launch()`.

Comment: it looks like .button() is getting executed as I can see the "pencil" icon. Is there any class I should be adding to make it look like active? or am I missing the button initialization (if there is any) ?

Comment: Can you recreate it (in a snippet in your question (edit, click `[<>]`)) with *just* the button - ie remove the modal code.  See [mcve].

Comment: Your button looks "normal".  It's just the rubbish jquery-ui default "theme" and icon that makes it look disabled.  Compare with an *actual* disabled button `.button({disabled:false})` and you'll see.  Here's one I prepared for you https://jsfiddle.net/uej4rpmL/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function onApplyBtnClick() {
    var dialogBox = $("<div>", {
        title: "Test Dialog"
      })
      .css("background-color", "#FFFFFF")
      .dialog({
        modal: true,
        close: function() {
          $(this).remove();
        },
        buttons: {
          "Apply": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });

    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      id: "schpn12",
      value: "ABCD"
    }).appendTo(dialogBox);

    $("<button>", {
        class: "editbtn"
      })
      .html("Edit")
      .button({
        icons: {
          primary: "ui-icon-pencil"
        },
        showLabel: false
      }).appendTo(dialogBox);
  }

  $("#applybtn").click(onApplyBtnClick);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="applybtn">Apply</button>
```

Since you are building the Dialog, Input, and Buttons, it may be best to initialize them as you create them.

`text` is not a Option or Method of Button. You will want to use `showLabel` Option.